# Rails : change user preference form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model-view-controller

I have an User model who `has_one :preference`, but I would like to join the form to update the user and the form to update his preference, so in the user's form, I added :

```
<% if !@user.new_record? %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'user_preference_quote_type', 'Type de citations' %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag 'user_preference_quote_type', @user.preference.quote_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'user_preference_locale', 'Langage' %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag 'user_preference_locale', @user.preference.locale %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller :

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.preference.quote_type = params[:user_preference_quote_type]
    @user.preference.locale = params[:user_preference_locale]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => t('c.users.update')) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But the preferences would not change, how can I do it ? And is there is better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good way of doing that. You should use [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for). It will make your form cleaner. By the way, what you're doing in the controller is not working because you use `update_attributes` to update your model that makes your assigments useless. Using the above mentioned `fields_for` will help you to clean the controller too. But be careful because you surely will need [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) in your model.

Comment: Thank you, I was sure there is something beautiful for this in Rails, but couldn't find it :(.

Answer (score 0):

Check out nested_attributes: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for